# What would be the practical steps towards helping a friend taking a decision to become a Muslim

Tags: practical-islam, islamic-basis, christianity, dawah

Al Salam Alikum,

I have a Christian friend who has a genuine interest in Islam,
I would like to know what are the steps I can take in order to help her feel more secure regarding Islam, and eventually to be a true Muslim.

I know that I have no experience in that field, yet I can answer and explain a good amount of questions about Islam, I know that is not enough thou, therefore I want to educate myself to be able to do this task.

at the same time, I don't want to miss this opportunity by approaching to the idea of Islam in a wrong way, which may let her feels insecure and pushed to do something she does not want to do.

I'm considering going to an Islamic center, these people have the right experience in that field, but it is early for that, and before that step, I want to know what are the steps appropriate for such a task.

Comment: Hello Rami and thank you for the question. This site is to answer questions about and on the subject of Islam. We invite you to reach out to a real life resource for this question because they are far better off the random folks on the net.

Comment: If it's a "she" then perhaps it is a good start to tell her about benefits of hijab. Here is a TV talkshow which I think puts it in the right perspective for anyone to understand: www.youtube.com/watch?v=VPNsGJEPT9Y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the original question,

Brother Asalamu Alaykum. First of all you should give her a translation of Qur'an in any language which is suitable for your friend and Biography of Muhammad, From Martin Lings. The best award winning biography out there acceptable to ahl al sunnah wal jamaah.

Secondly, tell her to not make a decision in haste, and tell her to do research on Islam and let her ask Allah s.w.t in her prayers to guide herself to the right path. If possible ask her to memorize the Opening Chapter of Qur'an and recite it frequently, it asks for God's guidance. There are chances that God would give her a sign to move foreward as is happened with many converts when they ask God's help.

Thirdly, Tell her about God's knowledge. Islamic understanding of the one, omnipotent,omnipresent, omnibenevolent God. The best thing about Islam is Tahweed let her grow in the knowledge of God's oneness and show her that how everything points to the Divine Unity of God.

Fourthly, you also pray for her, we will do the same.

and at last, please update on her progress here itself if there is not a problem and you have time so that brothers can give more suggestions.

Wasalam.

Thirdly,

Answer (score 1):

Show your friend this video:-

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7d16CpWp-ok

And make sincere dua that Allah guides her.

Incase you are interested also, Sheikh Yusuf Estes talking about how he found his truth after being a christian preacher.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MH2RZfNXGdA

Comment: thank you for the replay, do you know any videos that show how Islam maintained the rights of individuals (man & women) and how Islam aimed to protect the family in order to build up a health society, I was thinking about what would be an appropriate subject to start with, and I guess starting with smooth, daily-life actions is the best thing to do in order to describe how Islam affect our daily-life towards a better life.

Comment: There is a book that you should show your friend. All of the answers are in it, called the QURAN.

Comment: If it's a "she" then perhaps it is a good start to tell her about benefits of hijab. Here is a TV talkshow which I think puts it in the right perspective for anyone to understand: www.youtube.com/watch?v=VPNsGJEPT9Y

Answer (score -2):

Asalamou Alakoum,
first you should now if he is a believer or not(he believe in god or not),
if he's than you should try to correct his misconception about God, for example if his christian than you try  to convince him about the unicity of allah and make him go out with some brother to make him understand the real impact of Islam in your life and how it make you a better person, this things will make your relation better and in this way he will ask a more question and he will be more comfortable and he will trust you, And Sure like brothers before me said you should try to give him a translation of Quran in his language, and if he read some page, ask him if he had problem, because some time translation does not give the real meaning, 
And baraka allhou fik,

```
إِنَّكَ لَا تَهْدِي مَنْ أَحْبَبْتَ وَلَٰكِنَّ اللَّهَ يَهْدِي مَنْ يَشَاءُ ۚ وَهُوَ أَعْلَمُ بِالْمُهْتَدِينَ
```

in this verse allah said to Rassoulou allah that his not the one how make people enter Islam  but is Allah how do this and the person it self,
because this arabic phrase mean the two thing in the same verse, Allah will guide the person and the person should want this guide, as muslim we have an obligation to make Da3oa, it will succeed with some, it will fail with others but those two things are not in our hand, even with Rassoulou Allah (the one that is better in every way possible, with all his kindness, knowledge) some have not accepted this religion, is not the mistake of Rassoulou allah or something like that, but those people did not want this path, w Baraka allou fik